# How can I extract .class files from .jar files?

Tags: ant

A quick question: I like the look of this bit of Ant:

```
<fileset dir="${lib}">  
   <patternset refid="myPattern" />  
</fileset>
```

So I could use this e.g. to copy a few .jar files from ${lib} that match myPattern.

What if what I really want is to look into each .jar in ${lib} and select only .class files that match myPattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`unjar`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) task does pretty much what you want here out of the box. Use a `fileset` to specify the jar files you want to extract from, and a `patternset` to specify which files to extract.

```
<unjar dest="${dest.dir}">
  <patternset refid="myPattern" />
  <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="*.jar" />
</unjar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`archives`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#archives) resource collection to extract several files from multiple archives:

```
<copy todir="somedir">
    <restrict>
        <!-- This is just an example, you can use any restriction -->
        <name name="somePattern"/> 
            <archives>
                <zips>
                    <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />
                </zips>
        </archives>
    </restrict>
</copy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'd need to unjar the jars and then do the copy of class files.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with antcontrib's [For task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html)

```
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <unjar src="@{file}" dest="${dest}">
      <patternset refid="myPattern>
    </unjar>
  </sequential>
</for>
```